# I cannot get my doubly linked list to delete a node within the list properly, it looks like it should work but doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

So, I have created a class that generates a generic doubly linked list. The problem is that the tester file keeps saying that I have done something incorrectly. It looks like it starts having problems with the deleting nodes portion of the test.

**This is the deletion portion of the tester.**

(The original numbers are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and the end result should be 1,3,4,5,6,7,8)

```
public static boolean deleteTest(GenDoubleLinkedList<Integer> intList)
{
    printDecorated("Removing Test\nRemoving first item, third item, and last item");
    intList.resetCurrent();
    intList.deleteCurrent();

    intList.goToNext();
    intList.deleteCurrent();

    while(intList.moreToIterate())
    {
        intList.goToNext();
    }
    intList.deleteCurrent();
    intList.print();
    return valuesMatch(intList,TEST_VALS_2);
}
```

**These are my deleteCurrent, moreToIterate, resetCurrent and goToNext methods.**

```
public void deleteCurrent() {
    if(current != null && prev != null) {
        System.out.println("DELETING " + current.data);
        current = current.nextLink;
        prev.nextLink = current;
        next.prevLink = current;

    }
    else if(current != null && prev == null) {
        System.out.println("DELETING " + current.data);
        head = head.nextLink;
        current = current.nextLink;
    }
}

public boolean moreToIterate() {
    //System.out.println(current.nextLink != null);
    if(current.nextLink != null)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void resetCurrent() {
    current = head;
    prev = null;
    next = current.nextLink;
}


public void goToNext() {
    //System.out.println(current.data);
    if(current != null) {
        current = current.nextLink;
        prev = current.prevLink;
        next = current.nextLink;

    }
}
```

(I have the System.out.println()'s to troubleshoot.)

**Here is what the console is outputting.**

[image]

From my system out it looks like it should be deleting the correct nodes but when the test runs it obviously did not delete the correct ones. I am at a standstill and cannot figure out the issue.

If I need to I can give the entire tester file along with any of my code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show methods `resetCurrent()` and `goToNext()`

Comment: Please post your code as code instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

current = current.nextLink should be changed to current = prev in your delete routine and current = current.nextLink should be removed from your "delete head" portion of your delete routine.

Please next time paste your cade it code tags so we can copy paste it to refer to it and also the line numbers...